# Using \dfrac within tabu repositions the baseline

Tags: tables, math-mode, xetex, pdftex, tabu

With this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=2mm
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|X|X[0.8,c]|}
\hline
With dfrac    & $\dfrac{1}{2}$ \\
\hline
Without dfrac & $\frac{1}{2}$ \\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

it can be noticed that on the first row the first cell's baseline has been lowered:

[image]

So, is there a way to keep all cells on the first column properly aligned to the top (i.e. keep their original baseline) while using large fractions elsewhere?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! sorry, but as far as my ayes serve me, i don't see this. both rows have equal positioned contents. or i misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Zarko It might be a little hard to notice, but please look at the white space above the "With dfrac" text

Comment: do made any measurement which confirm your observation? how big is difference in comparison to `\frac` (considering scaling of their size)? and also test, if this is happens only using `tabu` or you notice this at other table environments?

Comment: the baseline is at the same position relative to the math axis in both rows.  the difference in spacing is caused by the greater height of the `\dfrac`; the clearance of the highest point in both rows from the rule above it is, however, the same, "lowering" the apparent baseline of the `\dfrac` row.  apply `\smash` to both of the fractions and you will see a uniform baseline, but indeed the `\dfrac` fraction will be smashed between the surrounding rules with no clearance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the comment by barbara beeton: the larger size of the `\dfrac` pushes the full row down in order to obtain vertical alignment on the center of the line.

You can use `\smash` around the `\dfrac`, which processes the argument as if it has zero width and height. Then the baseline/center of the line is no longer influenced by the `\dfrac`, resulting in the desired top alignment for the left cell. However, now the cell on the right is no longer expanded, so the fraction does not fit anymore. To address this issue some extra vertical space can be added with `\vspace` (which does not influence the text baseline). To make it easier to use a new macro can be defined (`\mydfrac` in the example below).

The extra vertical space is hardcoded, which does not work properly if the fraction has a different size. The example below contains an extra macro where the space at the top and bottom can be supplied as the 3rd and 4th argument.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mydfrac}[2]{\vspace{2mm}$\smash{\dfrac{#1}{#2}}$\vspace{2mm}}
\newcommand{\mydfracsize}[4]{\vspace{#3mm}$\smash{\dfrac{#1}{#2}}$\vspace{#4mm}}

\tabulinesep=2mm
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {|X|X[0.8,c]|}
\hline
With default dfrac    & $\dfrac{1}{2}$\\
\hline
With adjusted dfrac    & \mydfrac{1}{2}\\
\hline
Without dfrac & $\frac{1}{2}$ \\
\hline
With custom size dfrac  & \mydfracsize{\sum_{i=0}^4 \sqrt{i}}{x}{3}{1}\\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]